# Error: Failed to lookup view "form" in views directory "./views"

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

fiz a configuração do modelo do guidão em meu arquivo app.js, mas quando tento executar meu código com nodemon ele me retorna este erro. alguém pode ajudar? Este erro foi gerado quando eu estava tentando resolver o erro "handlebars is not a function" e não consegui resolver

[imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li6yC.png)

Answer (score -2):

Eu consegui, só foi meu projeto que estava mal estruturado
[solução](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnLe1.png)